# Bad universal repeater and access point configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

my friend have problem with bad internet connections. The problem is that he have 
Access Point and Universal Repeater and they are bad(old). They use B+G standard but connection is bad and unstable. When you don't use internet you have like 10ms but when you download upload you have 2000ms and more.

One use 5460APv2_e18_eu_b4 and second 5460APv2_e18_eu_b5 fimeware.

[Access Point settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2ZDm.png)

[Universal Repeater settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im5gJ.png)

EDIT Internet connection before this bridge is OK. It works great but after this bridge it is really bad.
Even when i want to change settings it takes few settings to load AccessPoint settings page.

EDIT x2 I will update fimeware to 5460APv2_e19_b3_eu on both routers maybe it will help

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the internet connection, not the access point. What kind of internet connection do you have? Try plugging your computer directly into your DSL/Cable modem/whatever and try your speed tests again. If you get the same results then the problem is with the modem or internet connection.

Comment: Also, just because something is old doesn't make it bad. I have a 10 year old car that still runs perfectly.

Comment: Internet Connection is OK on computers before bridge after bridge it is bad. Internet is shared between two building using tube so there many things that made connections worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating fimeware helped solve in small % each router. However the problem was poor connection between two router 11Mbps. I figured that they propably use 802.11b between them and forced 802.11g. Now connection improved to 18Mbps diffrence is small but I knew that the reason is bad signal. Propably i will try to found the reason or buy stronger routers.

EDIT I started experimenting with Fragment Threshold on Access Point. Results are amazing everything works better but I will try to improve this even more.